# Стиль форматирования С++ кода "JavaStyle"

Tags: ide, qtcreator

Достаточно продолжительное время использую QtCreator как основную и единственную IDE. В основном это проекты на C++. Однако с самого начала использования меня не устраивало автоформатирование кода. Дело в том, что распространенное для С++ форматирование кода меня совсем не устраивает. Буквально пару дней назад я нашел в сети описание способа форматирования, который я использую, и называют там его "JavaStyle". Короткий пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

typedef std::vector<uint> PathType;
typedef std::map<uint,bool> VisType;
typedef std::map<uint,std::vector<uint>> RelType;

void PrintPath(uint I, PathType P, VisType V, RelType &R) {
  if (V.find(I) != V.end()) return;
  P.push_back(I); V[I]=true;
  for(const auto& x: P) std::cout << ":" << x; std::cout << std::endl;
  for(const auto& i: R[I]) PrintPath(i,P,V,R);
}

int main() {
  VisType Vis;
  PathType Path;
  RelType Rel = {
    {0,{1,5,6}},
    {1,{0,2,6}},
    {2,{1,3,6}},
    {3,{2,4,6}},
    {4,{3,5,6}},
    {5,{0,4,6}},
    {6,{0,1,2,3,4,5}}
  };
  for(auto const& i:Rel) PrintPath(i.first,Path,Vis,Rel);
}
```

С некоторых пор неудобство автоформатирования как мне надо - начало сильно мешать. В настройках QtCreator'а я не нашел способа мне нужного, там фигурные скобки задаются жестко на следующей строке, лишь можно настраивать отступы.

**Вопросы:**

- есть ли возможность как-то настроить/"обучить с помощью плагинов" QtCreator для нужного мне автоформатирования?
- какие из прочих IDE обладают похожим функционалом QtCreator'а и позволяют нужное мне автоформатирование?

Comment: *"распространенное для С++ форматирование кода"* -- которое из них? Навскидку их штук 10 :)

Comment: Основное различие моего стиля и "всех остальных 10" - там переносят фигурные скобки, тем самым искусственно растягивают код. Мне это не нравится.

Comment: Посмотрите ссылку в моём ответе, раздел "Bracket Style Options". "Там" - это в каком из 12? Везде по-разному :)

Comment: Да, есть такое. И это оно: --style=java / --style=attach / -A2

Comment: В креаторе же есть возможность настройки стиля кода?

Comment: Да, но не вида переноса скобок - или я плохо искал?

Answer (score 1):

Делюсь способом, который использую везде, независимо от IDE или редактора. И везде получаю один и тот же результат. Единственное требование к способу - поддержка запуска внешних утилит (и QtCreator это умеет).

Способ очень простой: запуск [AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html) с нужными ключами в качестве этой самой внешней утилиты.

Плюс (но это уже на любителя) - pre-commit хук а-ля:

```
git diff --name-only | while read FILE; do

  if [[ "$FILE" =~ ^.+\.(c|cpp|h)$ ]]; then
    astyle -n "$FILE"
  fi

done
```

Настройки astyle хранятся в глобальном конфиге, поэтому здесь можно указывать только ключ `-n` при необходимости (не создавать бэкапы).

Естественно, вместо astyle может использоваться любая другая утилита.

Comment: Так это пост-форматирование, не?

Comment: @Majestio, *"запуск AStyle с нужными ключами в качестве этой самой внешней утилиты"*. [Документация к QtCreator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-external.html).

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Вчера собрал QtCreator 4.1.0 и там в настройках увидел "Стилизатор", в том числе и AStyle. Поразбираюсь, если форматирование будет в процессе набора, а не только сохранения - значит в точку.